# static variables behave differently in maven jars and eclipse runnable jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, apache-flink

I need to use variables initialized in outer class to be used in inner class.So I had used static variables.Also this is Flink application.

When built as eclipse-export-runnable jar --it works fine--state of variable retains

When built as maven or eclipse-export-jar--it fails--state of variable lost

FileMonitorWrapper.fileInputDir--values is "" and don't fetch the passed value.

Sounds strange..any thoughts

```
static transient String fileInputDir="";
static transient String fileArchiveDir="";
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public DataStream<String> ScanDirectoryForFile(String inputDir, String inputFilePattern,String archiveDir, StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
    try {
        FileMonitorWrapper.fileArchiveDir = archiveDir;
        FileMonitorWrapper.fileInputDir = inputDir;
                    filteredDirFiles = dirFiles.filter(new FileMapper());
    .
    .
    .
    }
    }



     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 static class FileMapper implements     FilterFunction<TimestampedFileInputSplit>{
      @Override
  public boolean filter(TimestampedFileInputSplit value) throws Exception {

    if(value.toString().contains("done")) 
        FileMonitorWrapper.doneFound = true;
    if(value.toString().contains("dat"));
        FileMonitorWrapper.datFound = true;
    if(FileMonitorWrapper.datFound && FileMonitorWrapper.doneFound) {
        try {
        if(value.getPath().toString().contains("done")) {
            Files.move(Paths.get(FileMonitorWrapper.fileInputDir+"\\"+value.getPath().getName()),
                    Paths.get(FileMonitorWrapper.fileArchiveDir+"\\"+value.getPath().getName()));
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (!value.toString().contains("done"));
    }
    else 
        return false;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: *"Sounds strange..any thoughts"*  - It is impossible.  There must be another explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, serialization of POJOs does not capture the state of static variables.  From what I have read about it, Flink serialization is no different.

So when you say that the static variable state is "retained" in some cases, I think you are misinterpreting the evidence.  Something else is preserving the state of the static variables OR they are being initialized to the values that *happen to be* the same in the "before" and "after" cases.

---

Why am I so sure about this?  The issue is that serializing static variables doesn't make much sense.  Consider this

```
public class Cat {
    private static List<Cat> allCats = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private String colour;

    public Cat(...) {
        ...
        allCats.add(this);
    }
    ...
}

Cat fluffy = new Cat("fluffy", ...);
Cat claus = new Cat("claus", ...);
```

If the static field of `Cat` is serialized:

1. Every time a serial stream contains a `Cat` it will (must) contain all cats created so far.
2. Whenever I deserialize a stream contains a `Cat`, I also need to deserialize the `ArrayList<Cat>`.  What do I do with it?

   - Do I overwrite `allCats` with it?   (And lose track of the other cats?)
   - Do I throw it away?
   - Do I try to merge the lists?  (How?  What semantics?  Do I get two cats called "fluffy"?)

Basically, there is no semantic for this scenario that is going to work out well *in general*.   The (universal) solution is to NOT serialize `static` variables.